# Selenium Web Driver element not interactable error occurring with Python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am new to Python and am trying to set up a simple automation test to input some data into fields, but am running into a problem with two fields in particular.

Here is my code that I am running:

```
 #!/usr/local/bin/python3
 #Reset CP Passwords import getpass import time from selenium import webdriver

 #Opens chrome  browser = webdriver.Chrome() browser.get('https://10.103.41.107/Login/') loginError =
 browser.find_element_by_class_name('loginerror')



 #Enters Username credentials print('Please enter your cp username') cpUsername = input() print('Please enter your cp password') cpPassword
 = getpass.getpass(prompt='Password: ', stream=None) 


 #Enters Login information searchUsername = browser.find_element_by_name('EnteredUserID')
 searchUsername.send_keys(cpUsername) searchPassword =
 browser.find_element_by_name('Password')
 searchPassword.send_keys(cpPassword)

 clickSubmit = browser.find_element_by_link_text('Login')
 clickSubmit.click()

 time.sleep(3)

 browser.get('http://10.103.41.107/Operator/System/DeviceTags/Modify/Add/index.jsp')

 time.sleep(3) searchValue =
 browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#tagValue') searchValue.click()
```

Below are the errors I am receiving. To note, I am able to use .send_keys on lines 16 and 18 with no problems. I added some waits in between in case it had problems loading the elements in time as well.

```
   File "test2.py", line 37, in <module
     searchValue.send_keys('test')   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py",
 line 479, in send_keys
     'value': keys_to_typing(value)})   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py",
 line 633, in _execute
     return self._parent.execute(command, params)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
 line 321, in execute
     self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py",
 line 242, in check_response
     raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message:
 element not interactable   (Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.131)  
 (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6
 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Mac
 OS X 10.14.4 x86_64)
```

screenshot of the elements below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmYBT.png)

Comment: To add, I added the .click() function there to make sure the element could be selected, this works without issue and just fails at .send_keys()

Comment: using the same code, I used the FireFox driver instead and it works, still really unsure why this would only be failing in Chrome

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your question. Right now you have a lot of code inside a quote tag and using heading styles and it looks like it's yelling. All code should be formatted as code. If you are unsure how to do that, there is a help section in the editor.

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: Jeff, thanks for your input. Still new here but updated everything and read the post. Tyvm.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a bit of research, this is a bug with this version of chrome driver in v74. I downgraded a few versions and had no issues.